# Css clip path inside another clip path not working properly (REACT)

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I'm using react on a project and I'm trying to figure out how to make a combination of two clip path. But they are interacting in some way. if I deactivate the css line (clip) of the parent component the clip-path work fine on the child component but if both work at the same time I get a visual error. The backdrop blur doesn't get the masking and the background color works fine.

// Initial State
[image]
// Disabling parent clip-path
[image]

[image]

// HTML(JSX) parent

```
import React from 'react'

import ImgSlider from '../config/ImgSlider'
import logoWhite from '../img/logo-white.png'


export default function start() {
  return (

    <div className="container-inside" >
    
    <div className='container-start'>
      <h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>¡Personalizá tu regalo!</h1>
      <div className='button-start'>
      <svg className='svg'>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="starClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0.5,0.76 L0.277,1 L0.321,0.672 L0,0.643 L0.278,0.474 L0.099,0.198 L0.401,0.315 L0.5,0 L0.599,0.315 L0.901,0.198 L0.722,0.474 L1,0.643 L0.678,0.671 L0.722,0.999 L0.5,0.76"></path></clipPath>
        </defs>

      </svg>
        <button className="starClip">
            <h2>start</h2>
        </button>
      </div>
      <img className='logo'  alt="logo"/>
    </div>
    <ImgSlider />
    </div>
  );
}
```

// CSS parent

```
.clipped {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 87vh;
  background: #F2E9DB;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

// HTML(JSX) child

```
import React from 'react'

import ImgSlider from '../config/ImgSlider'
import logoWhite from '../img/logo-white.png'


export default function start() {
  return (

    <div className="container-inside" >
    
    <div className='container-start'>
      <h1 style={{color: 'white'}}>¡Personalizá tu regalo!</h1>
      <div className='button-start'>
      <svg className='svg'>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="starClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0.5,0.76 L0.277,1 L0.321,0.672 L0,0.643 L0.278,0.474 L0.099,0.198 L0.401,0.315 L0.5,0 L0.599,0.315 L0.901,0.198 L0.722,0.474 L1,0.643 L0.678,0.671 L0.722,0.999 L0.5,0.76"></path></clipPath>
        </defs>
        
        <g className="starClip" clipPath="url(#starClip)">
        <button>
            <h2>start</h2>
        </button>
          </g>
      </svg>
      </div>
      <img className='logo'  alt="logo"/>
    </div>
    <ImgSlider />
    </div>
  );
}
```

// CSS Child

```
.container-inside{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-start{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 19;
}



.button-start{
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}



.starClip {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.186);
  box-shadow: 0.5vh 0.5vh 1.3vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0.5vh 0.5vh 2vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#starClip);
  clip-path: url(#starClip);
  z-index: 15;
}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a runnable snippet - including the svg markup for both clip-paths.

Comment: I don't know how to do that :c

Comment: Inspect your app in dev tools (as you already did) select the outermost (relevant) div - probably ... `.left` and copy the rendered markup via rightclick/copy element. You can use e.g a codepen to check, if the output. Copy the css (your current css code might suffice) and make sure the outer clip-path is included - I guess it's the inline svg within `.left`. Otherwise you can use a service like codesandbox - afaik you can create previews based on actual react code.